# Is there anyway to reorder of row <tr> in table by css?

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a table with 3 row like below. How can I change the order of row by CSS?
Example:

1. Name: A B C
2. Age: 1 2 3
3. Country: US CA CN

And I want it become:

1. Country: US CA CN
2. Name: A B C
3. AGE: 1 2 3

```css
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .value {
      text-align: right;
    }
    td {
      padding: 2px 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <table class="details">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="name">
          <td class="label"><label for="name">Fullname</label></td>
          <td class="value name-wrapper">Ann Smith</td>
          <td class="value name-wrapper">Beck Jackson</td>
          <td class="value name-wrapper">Chang Winchester</td>        
        </tr>
        <tr class="Age">
          <td class="label"><label for="age">Age</label></td>
          <td class="value age-wrapper">26</td>
          <td class="value age-wrapper">19</td>
          <td class="value age-wrapper">54</td>
        </tr>    
        <tr class="Country">
          <td class="label"><label for="country">Country</label></td>
          <td class="value country-wrapper">CA</td>
          <td class="value country-wrapper">US</td>
          <td class="value country-wrapper">UK</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this with CSS? And if it's necessary, I should use flexbox and divs (as other users have pointed out), instead of a table.

Comment: @f-spin flexbox is not designed to create a table layout

Comment: of course is not @TemaniAfif. But only with CSS I don't think it is possible to change the order fo the `<tr>`. So I would reformulate:

In my opinion, you could create a layout, that simulates a table, with divs and flexbox (or better, with `display: grid`). Or use javascript, to switch the order of your table rows.

Comment: Because I can not change the the foreach code :( I think CSS will be easier...

Comment: could you use javascript, @SeCrEtBoY?

Comment: I don't good at js :( The foreach in php is list automatic, I can use reverse_arrays but Just reverse the order but I can not make custom order... Use JS will not use much resource?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flex-direction: column-reverse` on parent elements to reverse the order of their children. Use `flex-direction: row-reverse` for rows.

```css
tbody { display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; }
```

```html
<table class="details">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="name">
        <td class="label"><label for="name">Fullname</label></td>
        <td class="value name-wrapper"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Age">
        <td class="label"><label for="age">Age</label></td>
        <td class="value age-wrapper"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Country">
        <td class="label"><label for="country">Country</label></td>
        <td class="value country-wrapper"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It seems to works with the code you provided, but @TemaniAfif has a good point about multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this is to consider some visual *hack* by using transform. Make sure `border-spacing` is set to `0` to avoid complex calculation and be aware that this work fine if all the `tr` have **the same height**.

```css
tr {
  /*we move all the tr down by one row*/
  transform:translateY(100%);
}

tr.country { 
  /*we move the country tr up by two rows*/
  transform:translateY(-200%);
}

table {
 border-spacing:0;
}
td {
 padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<table class="details">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="name">
        <td class="label"><label for="name">Fullname</label></td>
        <td class="value name-wrapper">name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="age">
        <td class="label"><label for="age">Age</label></td>
        <td class="value age-wrapper">26</td></tr>
        
    <tr class="country">
        <td class="label"><label for="country">Country</label></td>
        <td class="value country-wrapper">US</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with `flex` and [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) and position them however you want. Disclaimer, with this solution `tr` won't have `display: table-row-group` so you'll have to write additional css for positioning your cells:

```css
tbody {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

tr:nth-child(2) {
  order: -1;
}

tr:nth-child(1) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<table class="details">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="name">
        <td class="label"><label for="name">Fullname</label></td>
        <td class="value name-wrapper">name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Age">
        <td class="label"><label for="age">Age</label></td>
        <td class="value age-wrapper">26</td></tr>
        
    <tr class="Country">
        <td class="label"><label for="country">Country</label></td>
        <td class="value country-wrapper">US</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Updated** added updated HTML.

Comment: check the fiddle I sent, we no more have a table layout when applying your code

Comment: Ah, yes this affects the css.